# How to ensure that a server can process only one request at a time

Tags: nginx

I am currently developing a microservice in Go (net/http) with Nginx web server to serve requests from the internet. My use case demands that this server MUST process only ONE request at a time. If multiple requests come in at the same time, it must be able to wait until the current request finishes (or timeouts) and then serve the next one (in order of arrival or FIFO). I am wondering if this has to be handled at the application (Go) layer, or at the web server (Nginx) layer. My instinct drives me to handle this at the web server layer, but I am unsure. Is this possible? If so, how would you handle this at the web server (Nginx) layer?

Comment: No, you do this in your application. Web servers are not designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: Maybe doesn't apply to your model, but isn't this an appropriate scenario to use a message queue?

Comment: Last year I had this issue for a project I was working on. After a lot of research I just ended up using a Redis queue to process requests one at a time. Nothing to do with web server or application logic. Thanks @NicolasCastro!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web servers or application logic have their own responsibility, that is to serve requests and process application logic. It is neither one's responsibility to handle requests sequentially. This has to be done by means of a message queue, such as RabbitMQ, Redis, AWS SQS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you can achieve this in server configuration by specifying [worker_connections](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_connections) to a value of 2 (one for client-side and one for connecting to FastCGI to read app response, etc.) and setting `worker_processes` to `1`.

Then NGINX can only server single client only, at any given time.

Comment: Yes, but you absoutely should not even think about doing this.

Comment: @MichaelHampton could you elaborate on why is this a terrible idea?

Comment: @flizana The bits you actually have to synchronize probably take milliseconds to do. You can still process lots of requests even if they are serialized in your application. But this just hobbles the web server to no real purpose. After all, it has to do other things than simply proxy to your microservice. It has to proxy to other microservices, deliver images and other static content, etc.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for the response, actually after doing some more research I realised this HAS to be at the application layer, because it is the application logic that needs to be handled one at a time, not the server itself. I think I need to use mutexes to handle this.

Comment: @flizana And it's easy enough. Remember that `net/http` will put each incoming request into a goroutine, so you don't have to. Just [lock](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/9) the critical section and you're done.